# Conting Homomorphisms from a cyle to another graph

Tags: graph-theory

There is a question that requires me to show that the number of Homomorphisms from a cycle of length n to a graph is the number of closed walks of length n in the second graph.

Comment: Probably should be the number of closed walks, i.e., walks where the first and last vertices coincide.

Comment: Yah thanks Prof, it is that, I'll make corrections to the question

Comment: How can one go about this @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: This is pretty straightforward if you just pay attention to the definition of *graph homomorphism*. Let $C_n$ be an $n$-cycle with vertex set $V=\{v_0,\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$ and edges $\{v_k,v_{k+1}\}$ for $k=0,\ldots,n-2$, and the edge $\{v_{n-1},v_0\}$. Let $G=\langle U,E\rangle$ be any graph. A homomorphism from $C_n$ into $G$ is a map $f:V\to U$ such that if $\{v_k,v_\ell\}$ is an edge of $C_n$, then $\{f(v_k),f(v_\ell)\}\in E$.

- Show that $f:V\to U$ is a homomorphism, then $f(v_0),f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_{n-1}),f(v_0)$ is a closed walk in $G$ of length $n$; call this walk $W_f$.
- Now let $w_0,w_1,\ldots,w_{n-1},w_0$ be a closed walk $W$ of length $n$ in $G$. Use the idea of the previous point to find a homomorphism $f_W:V\to U$ corresponding to this walk.
- Show that the maps $f\mapsto W_f$ and $W\mapsto f_W$ are inverses. That is, if you start with a homomorphism $f$, find the corresponding walk $W_f$, and then find the homomorphism $f_{W_f}$ corresponding to that walk, you get the original homomorphism $f$, and if you start with a walk $W$, find the corresponding homomorphism $f_W$, and then take the walk $W_{f_W}$ correspoonding to that homomorphism, you get the original walk $W$. This establishes a bijection between the set of homomorphisms of $C_n$ into $G$ and the set of closed walks of length $n$ in $G$.

Comment: This is pretty good @Brian

Answer (score 0):

This is how I can prove this one, Let $f_i (V(C_n))$ be a homomorphism from $C_n$ to any graph $X$, then we claim that if $v_0, v_1, v_2,..., v_{n-1}, v_n$ are vertices in $V(C_n)$ then $f(v_0),f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_{n-1}),f(v_n), f(v_0)$ is a walk of length $n$ given that  $v_0, v_1, v_2,..., v_{n-1}, v_n, v_0$ is an n-cycle.

Suppose our claim is false, that is $f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_{n-1}),f(v_n), f(v_0)$ is not a walk then,  $X$ has at least two components then $f_i^{-1}X=C_n$  is disconnected which a contradiction; and that also means  $f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_{n-1}),f(v_n), f(v_0)$ is a walk of length less than $n$. which mean if $n$ is even then $C_n$ is bipartite, that is every even cycle is bipartite, which means $X$ must also be bipartite, then the length of  the walk 
$f(v_0),f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_{n-1}),f(v_n), f(v_0)$ has length at most $n-2$.
Having length $n-2$ means that there exists an independent set $ \lbrace f(v_i),f(v_j), f(v_k) \mid f(v_i)=f(v_j)= f(v_k)  \rbrace $, which which mean is a contradiction to fact that $f$ is a homomorphism. The argument also follows if $n$ is even. Hence $f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_{n-1}),f(v_n), f(v_0)$ is a walk of length $n$

We would let $W_t$ be any other closed  walk in $X$ that has length $n$ in $X$. We claim that there is an homomophism $\theta $ that  maps the cycle  to  this walk . Suppose this is not true, then $\lbrace v_1, v_2 \rbrace \in E(C_n)$ implies that implies that $\lbrace f(v_1), f (v_2) \rbrace \notin E(W_t)$,  this is a contradiction.

Hence, hence for every walk in $X$, there is homomorphism from $C_n$ to $X_n$. It follows therefore that we have proved the required result.